# Can't locate object method "strftime" via package

Tags: perl, datetime

I have written a perl script, where I call a subroutine to insert the fields into a database table. The subroutine is called in another file Test.pm other than the main perl file Test.pl.
In Test.pm I have the following fields to insert into table

```
my $date = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
my $time = localtime->strftime('%H:%M:%S');
```

But, here I get the following error

```
Can't locate object method "strftime" via package
```

What is this error and why does this occur. If I pass the parameters of `$date` and `$time` from `Test.pl`, the script works fine , how can I solve this?

Below is the subroutine :

```
sub send_message
{
     my $date = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
     my $time = localtime->strftime('%H:%M:%S');
     print "Date : $date Time : $time";
     my $sql1 = "Insert into testtable(time,date) values('$time','$date')";
     my $sth1 = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
        $sth1->execute
        or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First: the error means that your script wants to call the method `strftime` which shall be defined in a special package.
Looking at your script, the following happens:

1. you are calling `localtime` which is a method and returns the current time as a string, e.g.  `"Thu Jun 20 01:14:01 2013"`
2. you try to call the method `strftime` defined in a package (module) with the name returned by `localtime`. That doesn't work.

`strftime` is defined in `POSIX` and takes >1 parameters: the format and the time.
You probably want to call:

```
use POSIX;

my $date = POSIX::strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', localtime);
my $time = POSIX::strftime('%H:%M:%S', localtime);
```

or, because you're calling this method twice:

```
use POSIX;

my @localtime = localtime;
my $date = POSIX::strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', @localtime);
my $time = POSIX::strftime('%H:%M:%S', @localtime);
```

since `localtime` returns an array which should be the input to strftime.

Comment: I got this error Undefined subroutine &Message::strftime called

Comment: ok, sorry. You have to import strftime. Looks like it depends on perl version. Worked for me in a quick test. I edit my post.

Comment: I edited my post. Either write `use POSIX qw(strftime)` at the beginning or use `POSIX::strftime(...)` in the code.

Comment: However, after taking a look at the comment from Richard Huxton and inspecting `Time::Piece` it looks like your code snippet has been written for it. You should try that first.

Comment: I found one bug in my code (how did it get there) and edited the post again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32046/discussion-between-karsten-s-and-rudra)

Answer (score 6):

Close @Jim Garrison, but I think it's a missing [use Time::Piece](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Piece/) issue.

@Rudra - try adding that to the top of your script and see if it does the job.

Comment: If you want it to work in Test.pm, you have to `use` it there too. A `use` in the main package just imports into the main package, not into all other loaded modules. And since the question didn't mention Time::Piece (a module I never heard of until now) I think the other answers were reasonable in that they are actually correct in the absence of overridden core functions!

Comment: Actually, it's a core module. Frequently overlooked though.

Answer (score 0):

`localtime` is a builtin function and `strftime` is part of the `POSIX` package, so you don't use `->` syntax.  The best reference is at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html). For example

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$now_string = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", localtime;
# or for GMT formatted appropriately for your locale:
$now_string = strftime "%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y", gmtime;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it

Comment: Edited to include an example

Comment: Nuh uh, `Time::Piece` core module also has a `strftime` method, and it uses the `$t->strftime(...)` syntax where `t` is a `Time::Piece` object.

Comment: If the OP had included `Time::Piece` anywhere in the post the answer would be different.